# Standardize not among columns, but small parts of columns, using R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I have a multilevel structure, and what I need to do is standardize for each individual (which is the higher level unit, each having several separate measures).

Consider:

```
  ID measure score
1  1       1     5
2  1       2     7
3  1       3     3
4  2       1    10
5  2       2     5
6  2       3     3
7  3       1     4
8  3       2     1
9  3       3     1
```

I used `apply(data, 2, scale)` to standardize for everyone (this also standardizes the ID and measure, but that is alright).

However, how do I make sure to standardize seperately for `ID == 1`, `ID == 2` and `ID == 3`?
--> 
Each `observation` - `mean of 3 scores`, divided by `standard deviation for 3 scores`).

I was considering a `for` loop, but the problem is that I want to bootstrap this (in other words, replicate the whole procedure a 1000 times for a big dataset, so speed is VERY important).

Extra information: the ID's can have variable measurements, so it is not the case that they all have 3 measured scores.

The `dput` of the data is:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), measure = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), score = c(5L, 7L, 3L, 10L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", "measure", "score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Look at package `plyr` (function `ddply`).

Comment: Please give sample data or reproducible example so that good people here can help you better. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @geektrader This sample data suffices in my opinion.

Comment: @Dualinity Sufficient or not, it is a good practice to give your data in a form which can be easily pasted into R locally. Currently one needs to retype your data from scratch instead of pasting. It is easier when you do this: mydata <- data.frame(x1=..., x2=...)

Comment: I think the piece of data illustrates good enough the problem, I edited the question according to the previous comments.

Comment: @Jilber, I don't think it's unfair to put the burden on the OP to provide a *reproducible example*. I've removed my down-vote after your edit.

Comment: @MaximKovalenko I agree with you. Next time I'll supply the code to be able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an `lapply` with `split` solution and assuming your data is `DF`

```
> lapply(split(DF[,-1], DF[,1]), function(x) apply(x, 2, scale))
$`1`
     measure score
[1,]      -1     0
[2,]       0     1
[3,]       1    -1

$`2`
     measure      score
[1,]      -1  1.1094004
[2,]       0 -0.2773501
[3,]       1 -0.8320503

$`3`
     measure      score
[1,]      -1  1.1547005
[2,]       0 -0.5773503
[3,]       1 -0.5773503
```

An alternative which produces the same result is:

```
> simplify2array(lapply(split(DF[,-1], DF[,1]), scale))
```

This alternative avoids using `apply` inside `lapply` call.

Here's `split` divides the data into groups defined by `ID` and it returns a list, so you can use `lapply` to loop over each element of the list applying `scale`.

Using `ddply` from plyr as @Roland suggests:

```
> library(plyr)
> ddply(DF, .(ID), numcolwise(scale))
  ID measure      score
1  1      -1  0.0000000
2  1       0  1.0000000
3  1       1 -1.0000000
4  2      -1  1.1094004
5  2       0 -0.2773501
6  2       1 -0.8320503
7  3      -1  1.1547005
8  3       0 -0.5773503
9  3       1 -0.5773503
```

Importing your data (this is to answer the last comment)

```
DF <- read.table(text="  ID measure score
1  1       1     5
2  1       2     7
3  1       3     3
4  2       1    10
5  2       2     5
6  2       3     3
7  3       1     4
8  3       2     1
9  3       3     1", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: By the way, thanks for showing how easy it is to import it like that!

Comment: If you add a little bit of explanation to it, I'll accept and upvote the answer (I'm not really sure yet what both functions do, while I'd be able to read it, I guess it improves the answer quality)

Comment: Btw, check the first part. The ddply solution seems good. For first ID: `scale(c(5,7,3))` -> `(0, 1, -1)`, but I cannot find these three values in that order in the first solution?

Comment: @Dualinity you're absolutely right, I edited the answer giving some explanation and fixing the mistake.

Comment: Btw as a benchmark, the first solution is around 2 times faster (based on 1000 repetitions). Thank you. Still, the ordering is not good yet in that solution?

Comment: If speed matters and your dataset is big or you have many IDs, `data.table` might be the way to go.

Comment: It roughly takes 1 second for running ddply once on the dataset. I guess that'll have to be acceptable.

Comment: @Jilber The lapply solution doesn't really yield a ready-to-go object. I was not able to get it to show up in the way `ddply` has it. I am supposing that transferring that solution into matrix format will at least take as much time as the ddply solution.

Comment: @Jilber how again did you do the amazing copy paste import for which you just copied the text as a string?

Comment: @Dualinity what you do mean? is it what I've just put in the edit? If so, I just copy and paste your DF into `read.table(text="PASTE-HERE", header=TRUE)`